# Using vuejs plugin on the main.js file

Tags: javascript, plugins, vue.js, vuejs2

Im trying to create a plugin for manage the Oauth2 token data in my vuejs app.

I created the plugin following some few tutorials that are available on the internet.

```js
var plugin = {}

plugin.install = function (Vue, options) {
  var authStorage = {
    getToken () {
      let token = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
      let expiration = localStorage.getItem('expiration')
      if (!token || !expiration) {
        return null
      }
      if (Date.now() > parseInt(expiration)) {
        this.destroyToken()
        return null
      }

      return token
    },
    setToken (accessToken, expiration, refreshToken) {
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', accessToken)
      localStorage.setItem('expiration', expiration + Date.now())
      localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', refreshToken)
    },
    destroyToken () {
      localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
      localStorage.removeItem('expiration')
      localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token')
    },
    isAuthenticated () {
      if (this.getToken()) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  }

  Vue.prototype.$authStorage = authStorage
}

export default plugin
```

but when a try to access the methods on the main.js file, i get error saying that the object is undefined.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import AuthStorage from './AuthStorage.js'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(AuthStorage)

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requireAuth)) {
    if (!Vue.$authStorage.getToken()) {
      next({
        path: '/',
        query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${Vue.$authStorage.getToken()}`
}
/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

[image: chrome console showing the error]

Inside the components the plugin works as expected. The problem is when o try to use in the main.js file.
I already tried with: 
this.$authStorage
this.authStorage
Vue.authStorage

no success

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding `$authStorage` to the `prototype` of Vue.

```
Vue.prototype.$authStorage = authStorage
```

That means will only be available on instances of the Vue object (ie. the result of `new Vue(...)`.

If you want `$authStorage` to be available as a property of Vue without creating an instance, you need to add it as a static property.

```
Vue.$authStorage = authStorage
```

But, if it were me, I would probably take a different approach. I would likely build the AuthStorage plugin like this:

```
const authStorage = {
    getToken() {
      let token = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
      let expiration = localStorage.getItem('expiration')
      if (!token || !expiration) {
        return null
      }
      if (Date.now() > parseInt(expiration)) {
        this.destroyToken()
        return null
      }

      return token
    },
    setToken(accessToken, expiration, refreshToken) {
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', accessToken)
      localStorage.setItem('expiration', expiration + Date.now())
      localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', refreshToken)
    },
    destroyToken() {
      localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
      localStorage.removeItem('expiration')
      localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token')
    },
    isAuthenticated() {
      if (this.getToken()) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    },
    install(Vue) {
      Vue.prototype.$authStorage = this
    }
}

export default authStorage
```

Which would allow me to use it like this *outside* of Vue,

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import AuthStorage from './AuthStorage.js'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(AuthStorage)

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requireAuth)) {
    if (!AuthStorage.getToken()) {
      next({
        path: '/',
        query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

And reference it like this inside of Vue:

```
created(){
  let token = this.$authStorage.getToken()
}
```

Here is [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jn50vypjmv).