# Create a global snackbar using Vue, Vuetify and Vuex

Tags: plugins, axios, vuetify.js, interceptor, snackbar

I try to create a global snackbar to trigger every times an axios http error occurs, I followed this tutorial :  https://dev.to/stephannv/how-to-create-a-global-snackbar-using-nuxt-vuetify-and-vuex-1bda

But I don't want use Nuxt, only Vue, Vuex and Vuetify, so I tried to created a plugin available everywhere, but I get these errors : `[vuex] unknown mutation type: snackbar/showMessage` and `TypeError: Cannot read property '$snackbar' of undefined`.

Here is my code :

`src/main.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from "@/router";
import "./filters/filters";

import App from './App.vue'

import vuetify from "@/plugins/vuetify";

import VueSignaturePad from 'vue-signature-pad';
import axios from "axios";

import store from "@/store/snackbar";
import snackbarPlugin from "@/plugins/snackbar";

Vue.prototype.$http = axios;

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(snackbarPlugin, { store });
Vue.use(VueSignaturePad);

axios.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
        return response;
    },
    function (error) {
        // handle error
        if (error.response) {
            this.$snackbar.showMessage({ content: error.response.data, color: 'error', timeout: 10000 })
        }
    });

new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    vuetify,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

`src/store/snackbar.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        content: '',
        color: '',
        timeout: ''
    },
    mutations: {
        showMessage (state, payload) {
            state.content = payload.content
            state.color = payload.color
            state.timeout = payload.timeout
        }
    }
});

export default store;
```

`src/plugins/snackbar.js`

```js
const snackbarPlugin = {
    install: (Vue, {store}) => {
        if (!store) {
            throw new Error('Please provide vuex store.');
        }

        Vue.prototype.$snackbar = {
            showMessage: function ({
                                       content = '',
                                       color = '',
                                       timeout = ''
                                   }) {
                store.commit(
                    'snackbar/showMessage',
                    {content, color, timeout},
                    {root: true}
                );
            }
        };
    },
};

export default snackbarPlugin;
```

`src/utils/Snackbar.vue`

```js
<template>
    <v-snackbar v-model="show" :color="color" elevation="20">
        {{ message }}
        <v-btn color="accent" @click.native="show = false">
            <v-icon>close</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
    </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            show: false,
            message: "",
            color: "",
            timeout: 5000
        };
    },
    created () {
        this.$store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
            if (mutation.type === 'snackbar/showMessage') {
                this.message = state.snackbar.content
                this.color = state.snackbar.color
                this.timeout = state.snackbar.timeout
                this.show = true
            }
        })
    }
};
</script>
```

`src/App.vue`

```js
<template>
    <v-app>
        <Snackbar></Snackbar>
        <side-bar/>
        <Header/>
        <Main/>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
    import Snackbar from "@/utils/Snackbar";
    import SideBar from "@/components/layouts/SideBar";
    import Header from "@/components/layouts/Header";
    import Main from "@/components/layouts/Main";

    export default {
        name: 'App',
        components: {
            Snackbar,
            SideBar,
            Header,
            Main
        },
        beforeMount() {
            console.log('app')
            this.getRole()
            this.getEtats()
        },
        methods: {
            getRole() {
                this.$http.get('/rol')
                    .then(response => {
                        let agent = {}
                        agent.role = response.data.data.role
                        agent.username = response.data.data.username
                        localStorage.setItem('badge.agent', JSON.stringify(agent))
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            },
            getEtats() {
                this.$http.get('/nyx/badge/demande/accesnro/etats')
                    .then(response => {
                        localStorage.setItem('badge.etats', JSON.stringify(response.data.data))
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I purposely throw a 404 error on the `/role` route to bring up the snackbar but the errors occurs.

Please do you have any idea what's wrong when i call `this.$snackbar.showMessage ({content: error.response.data, color: 'error', timeout: 10000 })` in `main.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not use Vuex modules (https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html), you should call commit without snackbar prefix:

```
store.commit('showMessage',{
    content, color, timeout}
);
```

Check this post ([Using vuejs plugin on the main.js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379734/using-vuejs-plugin-on-the-main-js-file)). There is an explanation, how to use plugin in main.js and App at the same time.

main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import router from "@/router";
import "./filters/filters";

import App from "./App.vue";

import vuetify from "@/plugins/vuetify";

import VueSignaturePad from "vue-signature-pad";
import axios from "axios";

import store from "@/store/snackbar";
import snackbarPlugin from "@/plugins/snackbar";

Vue.prototype.$http = axios;

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(snackbarPlugin, { store });
Vue.use(VueSignaturePad);

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  function(response) {
    return response;
  },
  function(error) {
    // handle error
    if (error.response) {
      snackbarPlugin.showMessage({
        content: error.response.data,
        color: "error",
        timeout: 10000
      });
    }
  }
);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

snackbar.js

```
import store from "../store/snackbar";

const snackbarPlugin = {
  showMessage: ({ content = "", color = "", timeout = "" }) => {
    store.commit("snackbar/showMessage", { content, color, timeout }, { root: true });
  },
  install: (Vue, { store }) => {
    if (!store) {
      throw new Error("Please provide vuex store.");
    }
    Vue.prototype.$snackbar = snackbarPlugin;
  }
};

export default snackbarPlugin;
```

main.js

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In `main.js` i call the plugin `this.$snackbar.showMessage({ content: error.response.data, color: 'error', timeout: 10000 })`, the one that is supposed to call `store.commit ('snackbar / showMessage',{content, color, timeout},{root: true}); `
Isn't that supposed to work?

Comment: This call `this.$snackbar.showMessage({ content: error.response.data, color: 'error', timeout: 10000 })` is successful. The problem is with part `snackbar/showMessage` . The `snackbar` represent namespaced vuex module and `showMessage` name of your mutation. But you set your `showMessage` globally in your store. So vuex return error: `[vuex] unknown mutation type: snackbar/showMessage` You can easily call just `showMessage` or create snackbar module.

Comment: I added this at my store :
**snackbar: {
        namespaced: true,**

 But I have still this error :
 `TypeError: Cannot read property '$snackbar' of undefined at eval (main.js:45)` in main.js.
Maybe I can't use the key word `this` at this location to call my plugin ?

Can you show me what do you think please ?

Comment: I updated my answer above. Hope, it will help.